# Mouse not responsive using Nvidia Optimus

Tags: linux, laptop, mouse, optimus

Good day, I have a problem since I use bumblebee on my laptop on games the mouse is weird. Moves slowly like 100ms after I do the movement. Is there a way to fix this things? Thanks

Comment: It could be a problem with your driver. Have you tried to reinstall the driver. Also, does it possible to adjust PPI?

Comment: Yes I've reinstalled the driver. It doesn't work. I also tried another laptop and it is doing same problem with mouse.

Comment: If you have tried this mouse on another PC, then obviously it has a physical issue.

Comment: Mouse is working fine. On every PC with Windows, Mac or Linux on Desktop. There is only problem with laptops with nvidia optimus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `vblank_mode=0 primusrun %command%` to bypass gl_sync_to_vblank nvidia option. Disables defaultly enabled vsync.